# Embedded Kafka tests only succeeding when run from IntelliJ, fail on terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I have a few Embedded Kafka tests, here is the simplest of the bunch:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class KafkaConsumerTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    @Value("${kafka.fulfillment-topic}")
    private String topic;


    @Test
    public void messageListenerShouldReceiveMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        var fulfillmentContainer = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>) registry.getListenerContainer("fulfillment-listener");
        fulfillmentContainer.stop();

        var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        fulfillmentContainer.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(
                (AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener<String, String>) (consumerRecord, acknowledgment, consumer) -> latch.countDown());
        fulfillmentContainer.start();

        var result = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, "hello, world!");
        Assertions.assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)).isTrue();
    }
}
```

And then, I have a listener setup in a non-test class:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "fulfillment-listener", topics = "${kafka.fulfillment-topic}", groupId = "test-group")
public void listenForFulfillment(ConsumerRecord<?, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();

    taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
        // do stuff
    });
}
```

The purpose of the test is to intercept the call to this listener and confirm it happened. If I wish, I could forward the message onto the original listener (which I do in other tests). The issue is, when I run this via IntellJ it passes and the request is intercepted.

If I run this test on the terminal, it fails and the message is sent directly to the original listener ever touching my new one. Furthermore, if I simply stop the container via .stop() and never start it again then running via IntelliJ the message (as I would expect) never reaches the original listener, however running via the terminal `mvn test`, even when the container is stopped, the message somehow reaches the original listener.

This is happening for every single one of my Kafka tests and I have no idea how to solve it. All of them succeed when run via IntelliJ's built in test runner and yet they *all* fail when run via `mvn test`. If anyone has any insight into why, please let me know.

Additional info:
JDK:

```bash
➜  ~ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add failure message?

Comment: There is no failure message specifically, the new message listener simply never gets called and so the CountDownLatch is never decreased. If the message does reach the original listener then a JsonProcessingException will occur because the original listener has: `var fRecord = objectMapper.readValue(consumerRecord.value(), Request.class);``